# convert pandas series index to datetime

Tags: datetime, matplotlib

I have a pandas series/dataframe that has some built in time index which is of `pandas.core.indexes.base.Index` type. It goes like this:

```
Index(['2015-07-13', '2015-07-14',...],
      dtype='object', length=1238)
```

I want to convert this time index, a list-like thing to a list of strictly `datetime.date` type thing such that Matplotlib can plot the converted list on the x axis.
To be specific, I want it to be converted and have a format looking like this list:

```
[datetime.date(2015, 7, 13),datetime.date(2015, 7, 14),datetime.date(2015, 7, 15),
 datetime.date(2015, 7, 16),...]
```

Btw, the way I the list above is through this simple block of code:

```
dates = [datetime.date(2015, 7, 13)]

num=len(ts_test.index)
for _ in range(num-1):
    dates.append(dates[-1] + datetime.timedelta(days=1))
```

The problem is that the time index I try to plot on the x-axis skips weekends and such, so the list "dates" here has all the unwanted weekends and holidays.

so to put it simply, how to convert `'2015-07-13'`, a string to `datetime.date(2015, 7, 13)`?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to convert your index column, of type string, to an index column of type timestamp, a straightforward solution could be:

```
dates_test.index = pd.to_datetime(dates_test.index)
```

To extract a list later on:

```
timeList = dates_test.index.to_list()
```

Comment: You are absolutely right. This is a much simpler solution. It works just as well. I still can't quite tell datatime objects apart from timestamp objects, but somehow they are interchangeable with one another in terms of plotting "dates" using Matplotlib.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a solution and it works nicely!

```
dates_test=[]
for i in ts_test.index:
    date_str=i
    format_str='%Y-%m-%d' 
    datetime_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str, format_str)
    dates_test.append(datetime_obj.date())
```

So now you have managed to convert a list of str to a list of datetime type of objects which Matplotlib can fully handle and plot nicely along the X-axis!